# How should I specify a URI in the SophosLabs Intelix Malware and Productivity URL Lookup API?

Tags: sophoslabs-intelix

I'm trying to use the Malware and Productivity URL Lookup API  to perform a lookup for a URI.  The documentation suggests the form should be:

```
[ scheme ":" "//" ] [ userinfo "@" ] host [ ":" port ] path-abempty [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]
```

yet I'm getting the following results:

> - lookup https://www.frilfordheath.co.uk/ -> Not Found
> - lookup https://www.frilfordheath.co.uk  -> Not Found
> - lookup www.frilfordheath.co.uk/         -> Not Found
> - lookup www.frilfordheath.co.uk          -> Found

Code is JavaScript, and the URI are passed in as

```
encodeURI(linktocheck)
```

, but I'm getting the same results without encodeURI.

How should the URI be specified?

Comment: Phil's suggestion worked and I'm now getting the expected results coming through for my queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
encodeURIComponent(linktocheck)
```

instead.

From the docs, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI

```
encodeURI escapes all characters except:

Not Escaped:

    A-Z a-z 0-9 ; , / ? : @ & = + $ - _ . ! ~ * ' ( ) #
```

whereas encodeURIComponent escapes all characters except:

```
Not Escaped:

    A-Z a-z 0-9 - _ . ! ~ * ' ( )
```

Comment: Phil's suggestion worked and I'm now getting the expected results coming through for my queries.